# Game objects scaling up when transform.parent set to null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child

I'm working on a small game where objects are put in a boat, then a key press makes the boat "sail".

To move all the objects that are standing on the boat, i am setting the parent of each object to an empty guide object in the boat then changing the position of the boat. (I have also tried parenting the objects into the boat object itself)

The following is a script applied to the boat object.

variables set in the BoatScript class:

```
public class BoatScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public List<string> boatList;
    public KeyCode interact;
    public GameObject tempObject;
    public string whichSide;
    public string direction;
    public bool canSail;
}
```

Start and Update method:

```
void Start () {

    canSail = false;
    whichSide = "start";
    direction = "toFinish";
    speed = 0f;
}

void Update () {

    if (canSail == true)
    {
        SetSail();
    }

    if (boatList.Contains("FARMER") && whichSide == "start" && Input.GetKeyDown(interact))
    {
        speed = 0.5f;
        CharacterCheck();
    }
    else if (boatList.Contains("FARMER") && whichSide == "finish" && Input.GetKeyDown(interact))
    {
        speed = -0.05f;
        CharacterCheck();
    }   

}
```

Here are my OnTrigger methods:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log(other.gameObject.name + " collided with " + gameObject.name);
    promptText.text = "";

    if(CheckValidObject(other.gameObject.name) == true) { 

        boatList.Add(other.gameObject.name);
        logBox.text = logBox.text + "\nThe " + other.gameObject.name + " is in the boat";
    }

    if (other.gameObject.name == "FARMER")
    {
        promptText2.text = "Press E to set sail";
    }

}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    boatList.Remove(other.gameObject.name);
    logBox.text = logBox.text + "\nThe " + other.gameObject.name + " has left the boat";
    promptText.text = "";

    if (other.gameObject.name == "FARMER")
    {
        promptText2.text = "";
    }

}
```

Setting sail:

```
void SetSail()
{
    promptText.text = "";
    promptText2.text = "";

    addParents();

    if (whichSide == "sailing" && direction == "toFinish")
    {
        speed = 0.05f;
        gameObject.transform.Translate(speed, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (whichSide == "sailing" && direction == "toStart")
    {
        speed = -0.05f;
        gameObject.transform.Translate(speed, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (whichSide == "start" || whichSide == "finish")
    {
        gameObject.transform.Translate(speed, 0, 0);
        removeParents();
    }
}


void addParents()
{
    foreach(string o in boatList)
    {
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find(o);
        obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
        obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        if (obj.name == "FARMER") { obj.transform.parent = playerGuide.transform; }
        else {obj.transform.parent = itemGuide.transform; }

    }    

}

void removeParents()
{
    foreach (string o in boatList)
    {
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find(o);
        obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
        if(obj.name != "FARMER") {obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false; }        
        obj.transform.parent = null;
    }
}
```

The problem: Once the boat reaches and hits the collider for the other side, the boat stops as expected but the objects that were just removed from the parent begin to scale up continuously like this:

e.g 1 https://i.gyazo.com/d35ae729757b8e71c25fd1b4a3857dae.mp4

e.g 2 https://i.gyazo.com/80637919bfd114a42d187300b7faef25.mp4

I'm not too sure what is causing this. Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please read the manual on [How to provide a minimal complete and verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I feel there is code missing e.g. where does `whichSide` come from? Where is `canSail` set?

Comment: I have updated the question... those variables are declared globally in the BoatScript class, then set in the start method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are youu sure it is scaling up and not moving up in the Z axes? From what im looking it is going towards the camera but not scaling up. You should debug the position and scale in the update method to see whats really happening there.

Below comment: "Well then you will have to debug it more carefully, i would first try, setting canSail to false as soon as it reaches the end. Perhaps the method addParent which is always being executed is wrong, what does the object itemGuide does? edit: i just seen the second video, from my perspective that seems gravity, what you meant with problems with scaling up is because its moving out from the boat?"

Solution:

```
void SetSail()
{
    promptText.text = "";
    promptText2.text = "";

    addParents();

    if (whichSide == "sailing" && direction == "toFinish")
    {
        speed = 0.05f;
        gameObject.transform.Translate(speed, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (whichSide == "sailing" && direction == "toStart")
    {
        speed = -0.05f;
        gameObject.transform.Translate(speed, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (whichSide == "start" || whichSide == "finish")
    {
        gameObject.transform.Translate(speed, 0, 0);
        canSail = false; //Adding this line solves the issues, must have been affecting transform properties to child objects.
        removeParents();
    }
}
```

Comment: It does scale them up, if I push or pick up the chicken object, or move off the boat, they stretch and scale, updated the gif to show this better. If i inspect the objects in the scene hierarchy while playing the x,y,z scales are increasing.

Comment: Well then you will have to debug it more carefully, i would first try, setting canSail to false as soon as it reaches the end. Perhaps the method addParent which is always being executed is wrong, what does the object itemGuide does? edit: i just seen the second video, from my perspective that seems gravity, what you meant with problems with scaling up is because its moving out from the boat?

Comment: that was the problem. I set canSail to false in "SetSail()" at "else if (whichSide == "start" || whichSide == "finish")". I didn't notice that, very strange. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the parent via `transform.parent`, use `transform.SetParent(targetTransform, false);`. The second, bool, parameter determines if the game object's transform will maintain it's position, orientation, and scale. By setting it to false, the transform will maintain it's current values, while setting it to true will modify the position, orientation, and scale to maintain the world position. You can check this for further info [transform.SetParent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)